# 'select count' returns "OS reports: No such file or directory"

Tags: kdb

I get this

```
"./2017.10.14/:./2017.10.15/tableName. OS reports: No such file or directory"
```

when I try to do

```
select count i by date from tableName where date within(.z.d-5;.z.d)
```

works if I do

```
select colName from trackFeedStats where date within(.z.d-5;.z.d)
```

I assume it's one of the columns acting strange ...

**UPDATE**: the issue seems to be mainly when using `count i by colName1,colName2,colName3`

**UPDATE**: I checked permissions and everything seems to be alright, table is in the given partition (2017.10.14), no symlinks

**UPDATE**: I am looking for suggestions on fixing the db. the query is not that important

Comment: Have you tried .Q.chk? That would help 'fix' the database, it creates missing tables for you https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qchk-fill-hdb

Comment: That file path looks very odd with 2017.10.15 inside the 2017.10.14 partition. Have a look in that directory to see if someone hasn't accidentally saved something incorrectly there

Answer (score 0):

This can occur for a number of reasons:

1. The file/directory legitimately isn't there. Have you checked the database directories to see if the table is in each date slice? If not you should look into .Q.chk for filling missing dates.
2. You can also get this error if you don't have permission to read the files/directories in that database. They could have been written by a different user etc.

Comment: I checked the folder the table is there. I checked permissions and same user created the folder.

Comment: Did you check for hidden files and folders inside your date folders? As Matt Moore mentioned, the filepath in your error doesn't look right: `./2017.10.14/:./2017.10.15/tableName`, it's supposed to be something like `'./2020.09.30/tabB`

Comment: And as a general point, it's better to do something like `select count 1b by` on a date partitioned table rather than `select count i by`.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'count i' could be the culprit here.  It behaves strangely when applied against partitioned databases.

Although you have specified a list of dates in your where clause, under the hood, kdb is executing 'count i' against all table partitions in the database.

For reference, .Q.pn maintains partition counts -

```
q).Q.pn
tabA | 
tabB |
```

but, as demonstrated here, 'count i' will execute against all date partitions.

```
q)select count i from tabA where date within 2020.10.10 2020.09.12;
q).Q.pn
tabA | 8001 7998 8101 0 0 8002 8102 7940 7999 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
tabB | ()
```

For some reason, .Q.pn doesn't update if you add an additional constraint to your where clause.

```
q)select count i from tabA where date within 2020.10.10 2020.09.12,price>0;
q).Q.pn
tabA |
tabB |
```

and the query will actually run.  For example, in this database, there are some empty partitions for tabB.

```
q)select count i from tabB where date within .z.d + -7 0
'./2020.09.30/tabB. OS reports: No such file or directory
```

but, if we add some other constraint to the where clause, the query will run as we want it to.

```
q)select count i from tabB where date within .z.d + -7 0,not null sym
x
-----
16948
```

Running 'count' against a column will work.

```
q)select count sym from tabB where date within .z.d + -7 0
x
-----
16948
```

As a workaround, you could update your query to perform the 'count' against some key column, if one exists.  Alternatively, you could fill in the missing partitions, by running .Q.chk - https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qchk-fill-hdb

Comment: I think I am much more interested in fixing the db . the query is not that important.

Comment: Have you ran .Q.chk against your db?